# Bootstrap 4 selectpicker open modal based on selected value

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to get a selectpicker(with live search) to open a model when I only click on the option that says Add new contractor. My list is about 20 options long but it opens then model on all of them when I only want it to open on the one with value addnewcon. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the code

Because the default stockpicker doesn't load properly in BS4 ive decided to use this one. And in my JSfiddle I know the search isnt working but thats cause its a different js file.
[Flexible Bootstrap 4 Dropdown](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Bootstrap-4-Dropdown-Select-Plugin-jQuery.html)

Here is a link to my JSfiddle
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4o5xt2wa/)

Here is my code for the selectpicker

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_contractor">Select Contractor *</label>
            <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" id="contractor" name="contractor" required="required" data-error="Contractor is required.">
                            <option value="">Please select contractor</option>
       <option value="addnewcon">Add new Contractor</option>
                            <?php  foreach ($all_contractors as $con): ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $con['ID'] ?>">
                                <?php echo $con['Name'] ?>
                              </option>
                             <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>

          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="addnewcon" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem omnis aliquid voluptatibus, distinctio soluta eligendi officiis voluptatem necessitatibus magnam illum.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_addnewcon"></label>
            <BR>
            <BR>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addnewcon">Add new</button>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_location">Location/Project Name *</label>
            <input id="form_location" type="text" name="location" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter job location *" required="required" data-error="Location is required.">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_address">Address</label>
            <input id="form_address" type="text" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter job address">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_bore_length">Bore Length *</label>
            <input id="form_bore_length" type="number" name="length" class="form-control" placeholder="Estimate *" required="required" data-error="Bore length is required.">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_groundc">Assumed Ground Conditions *</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="groundc" required="required" data-error="Ground Conditions required">
                              <option value="">Assumed ground condition *</option>
                              <option value="Clay">Clay</option>
                              <option value="Mudstone">Mudstone</option>
                              <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
                        </select>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_jobstatus">Job Status *</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="jobstatus" required="required" data-error="Job Status Required">
        <option value="">Current job status *</option>
         <?php  foreach ($all_jobstatus as $jobstat): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo (int)$jobstat['ID'] ?>">
         <?php echo $jobstat['Status'] ?>
        </option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
                          </select>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form_start_date">Select Start Date(If Known)</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="startdate">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <p class="text-muted">
            <B><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</B>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
</body>
```

And here is my JS to open the modal

```js
 $("#contractor").change(function() {
  $(this).val() === 'addnewcon'
  $('#addnewcon').modal({
    show: true
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found my own solution, I figured it had to be something to do with the JS and this is what I came up with and works.

```
//Add new contractor
$("#contractor").change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() === 'addnewcon') {
    $('#addnewconmodal').modal({show: true});
  } else if ($(this).val() !== 'addnewcon') {
    $('#addnewconmodal').modal({show: false});
}

});
```